# How does Spring wire a OncePerRequestFilter with its init-param values?

Tags: spring-mvc, web.xml

I've got a simple [`OncePerRequestFilter`](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/current/api/org/springframework/web/filter/OncePerRequestFilter.html) with a couple of `init-param` entries defined in my `web.xml`, but I don't know how to access them from within the filter. `getFilterConfig()` returns `null`. The [`init(FilterConfig)` docs](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/current/api/org/springframework/web/filter/GenericFilterBean.html#init%28javax.servlet.FilterConfig%29) make it sound like it will do injection into bean properties based on the name of the `init-param`, e.g., a param named `foo` will have its value injected into a property on the filter named `foo`, but some logging in `doFilterInternal` seems to indicate that isn't happening.

Since I'm fairly new to modern Spring (last used it circa the 1.x days) and totally new to Spring MVC, I'm pretty sure I've just missed something obvious, but I can't see what it is. Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `init-param` values are mapped to properties of the filter it's self.

```
public MyFilter extends OncePerRequestFilter {

    // the following should be called once the `GenericFilterBean` `init` method has run        
    public void setFoo(String foo){
         this.foo = foo;
    }
}


<filter>
     <init-param>
          <param-name>foo</param-name>
          <param-value>bar</param-value>
     </init-param>
</filter>
```

Comment: That was my reading of the docs, but testing indicated it wasn't happening for some reason. Eventually, I just gave up and defined the values in my `applicationContext.xml`, which had the added benefit of making it easier to define a list of values for the property.

Comment: mmm... It really does do that or at least last time I used it (some 2-3 years ago), if it is still a problem try adding a break point in GenericFilterBean#init(FilterConfig). As a sanity check you could add `addRequiredProperty("wibble")` to your beans constructor..it should blow up.

Comment: I concluded that I must have something weird going on in my environment and went another route, but I accepted this answer because it matches with the documented behavior.

Comment: This didn't work for me as well, I have setter method which was never called by Spring, finally I had passed arguments to my spring bean instead of defining init parameters in web.xml

Comment: @GarethDavis Is it possible to read bar value for application.properties file?